# Spring batch: get ExecutionContext in the listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring batch.
I need to count the element read, written and that have gone in error.

I've defined a step like this:

```
/*...*/

@Bean
public Step stepMain(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepMain").<T, T> chunk(this.chuckSize).reader(reader(null, null)).processor(new Processor()).writer(writer()).faultTolerant().skipPolicy(new AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy()).listener(new ListenerReader()).listener(new ListenerProcessor()).listener(new ListenerWriter()).listener(new ListenerChunk()).build();
}

/*...*/
```

And, for example, an ListenerReader like this:

```
@Log4j2
public class ListenerReader implements ItemReadListener<T> {

    @Value("#{jobExecution.executionContext}")
    private ExecutionContext executionContext;

    @Override
    public void afterRead(T item) {
        Integer read = (Integer) executionContext.get("reportRead");
        read++;
        executionContext.put("reportRead", read);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadError(Exception ex) {
        Integer error = (Integer) executionContext.get("reportError");
        error++;
        executionContext.put("reportError", error);
    }

}
```

But in ListenerReader i've no visibility of executionContext field.
How can i solve?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible but could you maybe Autowire the ExecutionContext in?

Comment: try  @Value("#{stepExecution.getJobExecution.getExecutionContext}") instead, or @Value("#{stepExecution.jobExecution.executionContext}")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like

1. Define a Bean with JobScope
2. Use it in Step as usual
3. Inject it via Listener.

Below is an example

```
@Bean
@JobScope
public SimpleReaderListener simpleReaderListener() {
      return new SimpleReaderListener();
}

@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<SoccerTeam, SoccerTeam> chunk(1)
            .reader(simpleReader()).listener(simpleReaderListener()).processor(new SimpleProcessor())
            .writer(new SimpleWriter()).build();
}

public class SimpleReaderListener implements ItemReadListener<SoccerTeam> {

    @Value("#{jobExecution.executionContext}")
    private ExecutionContext executionContext;

    @Override
    public void afterRead(SoccerTeam soccerTeam) {

    }
```