# Spring Batch: How do I get the execution context into my ItemListenerSupport class?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Hopefully this is an easy one for someone: I want my Spring Batch app to make heavy use of the `ItemListenerSupport` "onError" methods to track all of the errors encountered in my job, and collect them all in an email at the end of the job. But isn't the only way to pass data in between steps in the `StepExecution` (to be promoted to the `JobExecution` later)? How do I get access to the `StepExecution` from an `ItemListener`? This may not be possible, because I swear I can't find an example of it.

A link to an example, or any kind of explanation, would be much appreciated!

UPDATE: Here's a link to a gist with my complete current configuration: **https://gist.github.com/cnickyd/cbfc6dd39bc2e266a5d2153678b7dc1c**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring batch: get ExecutionContext in the listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63936622/spring-batch-get-executioncontext-in-the-listener)

Comment: I saw that post and tried it, but IntelliJ reports that there’s no JobExecution to inject. But I’ll try it again when I get back to work. Thank you!!

Comment: Creating the jobScope listener bean gives me an error - "No context holder available for job scope". Do you have any insight into that?

Comment: Please share your code to be able to help you.

Comment: Will do. I"ll create a gist and post back here.

Comment: Here's my gist: https://gist.github.com/cnickyd/cbfc6dd39bc2e266a5d2153678b7dc1c I never shared one before, so please let me know if you can see it.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I also tried wiring a generic bean with JobScope. I didn't get context errors, but I added to the bean in my error processor, and in the afterJob it was null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a job scoped bean for that. What you can do is making your listener implement `ItemStream` and use the execution context to store what you need from your "onError" methods. Here is a quick example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.batch.core.ItemProcessListener;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.listener.JobExecutionListenerSupport;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStream;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Integer, Integer> itemProcessor() {
        return item -> {
            if (item % 2 != 0) {
                throw new Exception("no odd numbers here!");
            }
            return item;
        };
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MyItemProcessListener itemListenerSupport() {
        return new MyItemProcessListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(steps.get("step")
                        .<Integer, Integer>chunk(5)
                        .reader(new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)))
                        .processor(itemProcessor())
                        .writer(items -> items.forEach(System.out::println))
                        .faultTolerant()
                        .skip(Exception.class)
                        .skipLimit(10)
                        .listener(itemListenerSupport())
                        .stream(itemListenerSupport())
                        .build())
                .listener(new MyJobListener())
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJobConfiguration.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }
    
    class MyItemProcessListener implements ItemProcessListener<Integer, Integer>, ItemStream {

        private ExecutionContext executionContext;

        @Override
        public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
            this.executionContext = executionContext;
            this.executionContext.put("errorItems", new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }

        @Override
        public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeProcess(Integer item) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void afterProcess(Integer item, Integer result) {

        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void onProcessError(Integer item, Exception e) {
            List<Integer> errorItems = (List<Integer>) executionContext.get("errorItems");
            errorItems.add(item);
            executionContext.put("errorItems", errorItems);
        }
    }
    
    class MyJobListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {
        @Override
        public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
            // we know there is a single step here. But in a real world scenario, you would get the execution context of the step you need, or use an ExecutionContextPromotionListener and promote the key in the job execution context
            ExecutionContext executionContext = jobExecution.getStepExecutions().iterator().next().getExecutionContext();
            System.out.println("Sending email with error items: " + executionContext.get("errorItems"));
        }
    }

}
```

This prints:

```
2
4
6
8
10
Sending email with error items: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud! As usual, you were a big help!!